# Mac Homebrew and Wireshark

Tags: macos, wireshark, homebrew

I've installed Wireshark(.org) using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install wireshark
```

at the end the script says

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/wireshark/1.2.7 --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-wireshark
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
We don't build the X11 enabled GUI by default
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/wireshark/1.2.7: 167 files, 50M, built in 5.4 minutes
```

I'm not able to find the 'wireshark' GUI. 
Any idea of how to build it?

Thanks

Answer (score 106):

```
$ brew options wireshark
```

Shows you options for wireshark, which lists `--with-qt5`. QT is the GUI toolkit that Wireshark uses [since 1.10](http://www.wireshark.org/news/20140415.html). Thus, install wireshark using the following command:

```
$ brew install wireshark --with-qt5
```

Or if you already have wireshark previosly:

```
$ brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt5
```

If you do not add this option the commandline tool `tshark` will be installed.

Comment: Note that beginning with Wireshark `1.10.0` QT is used instead of GTK. So you can use the option `--with-qt`

Comment: `brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt`

Comment: First time I've ever had a formula not install by default. It would be better if there was a `--without-gui` instead of blindly continuing without any GUI which most who install wireshark are probably expecting.

Comment: @hanxue how do I run it after installing it?

Comment: I used the `reinstall` command, but to make it work I had to re-create the symlinks as explained in this [github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/32305#issuecomment-137328711):

rm '/usr/local/bin/wireshark' && brew link --overwrite wireshark

Comment: Just thought I'd add it appears the recommended option is now ```--with-qt5```. I received this warning when trying as defined above: *Warning: wireshark: --with-qt was deprecated; using --with-qt5 instead!*

Answer (score 9):

The new approach is to use `brew install wireshark --with-qt`.

The `--with-x` option no longer works.

More details on the switch to QT: https://blog.wireshark.org/2013/10/switching-to-qt/

Answer (score 4):

Well, the system did warn you that it wouldn't install the X11 GUI.
So maybe there is an option in the configuration phase that enables it?
You'd need a whole extra set of stuff to run X11.

At http://www.wireshark.org/download.html there is a binary downstaller you could use...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've X11, I just don't understand what I'm missing. I should build wireshark gui in some way I suppose... no mention of how to do it with homebrew. this is the script 'http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/wireshark.rb' sorry I'm newbie

Comment: Do it without the --disable-wireshark in the script. So edit the script... Maybe you'll get a problem with dependencies as well, so you could remove the --disable-dependency-tracking as well, but then of course you could get errors as well....
You do know that at the wireshark site there is a complete binary build of wireshark, installer and all ? That's a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Mac .dmg app installer from the http://www.wireshark.org website. You must wait a while for it to start X11. It will seem as though it is not working, but the app is just very slow.

Comment: Direct link: https://1.na.dl.wireshark.org/osx/Wireshark%203.0.6%20Intel%2064.dmg

Answer (score 2):

At some point, a cask formula was added. So the following command will actually install Wireshark, with the UI, as a regular app:

`brew cask install wireshark`

And you can then find it in Applications or via Spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have disabled the building of the GUI with the `--disable-wireshark` option to the configure script .

You need to clean up from the previous build, run configure without the `--disable-wireshark` and then rebuild.

Unfortunately I can't help you do this on your OS as I have no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is too low to comment on @jonchang's answer, and I realize that this is old, but in case others find this...

```
brew install wireshark --with-qt
```

as indicated in @jonchang's answer worked for me (use `brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt`, as mentioned by @Louis if you've already installed wireshark without qt).

As for running it, it doesn't install an OS X application, but
you should then be able to run qt from the command line:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wireshark/{{version}}/bin/wireshark-qt
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google in 2022, you're gonna want to try the following:

```
brew install wireshark --cask
```